# Execution location of Java Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, file

I have web service with my custom library. One of the classes in this library tries to read a file from local. Currently the file is in WEB-INF of Web Content folder of web service.  I'm using Apache Tomcat 7. Where should I put my file, so that my class in library can read the file.

Comment: @N K you can put your library and file at the same level i.e /WEB-INF/myfile and /WEB-INF/mylibrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this,

> System.err.println("Executing location : " + new
>   File(".").getAbsolutePath());

Got the location :)